# Creating a 4 State Mealy Finite State Machine using Verilog [HELP]

Tags: state, case, verilog, fsm

I'm trying to figure out how to get this to run without getting any errors.

```
module main;
(
    input wire clk, reset;
    input wire x, y;
    output reg n, c;
    s0 = 0,
    s1 = 1,
    s2 = 2,
    s3 = 3;
    
    state_reg; 
    state_next; 
);
always(posedge clk, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset) begin
        state_reg = s0;
    end
    else begin
        state_reg = state_next;
    end
end 

always (x, y, state_reg) begin 
    state_next = state_reg; 
    n = 0;
    c = 0;
    case (state_reg)
        s0 : begin
            if (x == 0 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0;
            end
            else if (x == 0 && y == 1) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
            else if (x== 1 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
             else if (x== 1 && y == 1) begin
                n = 1;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s1; 
            end
        end
        s1 : begin
              if (x == 0 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0;
            end
            else if (x == 0 && y == 1) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
            else if (x== 1 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
             else if (x== 1 && y == 1) begin
                n = 1;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s2; 
            end
        end
        s2 : begin
              if (x == 0 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0;
            end
            else if (x == 0 && y == 1) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
            else if (x== 1 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
             else if (x== 1 && y == 1) begin
                n = 1;
                c = 1;
                state_next = s3; 
            end
        end
        s3 : begin
             if (x == 0 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0;
            end
            else if (x == 0 && y == 1) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
            else if (x== 1 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 1;
                state_next = s3; 
            end
             else if (x== 1 && y == 1) begin
                n = 1;
                c = 1;
                state_next = s3; 
            end
        end
    endcase
endmodule
```

I feel like the code enough should show what I'm trying to do but in case it doesn't I've also attached an image of the logic schematic version (I'm not sure how to attach the .cct file of the schematic on this website due to me being new). Sorry guys this is somewhat my first time using Verilog so I'm really new to this but I have to write this for an honors project with zero guidance. So the output should be if I input x or y with either 0 or 1, it should switch to a different state depending on the conditions (s0, s1, s2, s3) etc. If I hit reset, it should go back to s0, if I hit clk or the clock variable, it should take the inputs x and y to decide what the next state should be.

EDIT: Here are the errors I'm getting.

```
jdoodle.v:2: syntax error
jdoodle.v:3: error: invalid module item.
jdoodle.v:6: syntax error
jdoodle.v:6: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:11: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:12: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:13: error: invalid module item.
jdoodle.v:14: syntax error
jdoodle.v:17: Syntax in assignment statement l-value.
jdoodle.v:18: syntax error
jdoodle.v:20: error: invalid module item.
jdoodle.v:21: syntax error
jdoodle.v:25: error: invalid module item.
jdoodle.v:26: syntax error
jdoodle.v:26: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:27: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:31: syntax error
jdoodle.v:31: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:32: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:33: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:36: syntax error
jdoodle.v:36: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:37: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:38: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:41: syntax error
jdoodle.v:41: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:42: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:43: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:46: syntax error
jdoodle.v:46: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:47: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:48: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:53: syntax error
jdoodle.v:53: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:54: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:55: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:58: syntax error
jdoodle.v:58: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:59: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:60: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:63: syntax error
jdoodle.v:63: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:64: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:65: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:68: syntax error
jdoodle.v:68: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:69: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:70: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:75: syntax error
jdoodle.v:75: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:76: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:77: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:80: syntax error
jdoodle.v:80: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:81: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:82: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:85: syntax error
jdoodle.v:85: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:86: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:87: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:90: syntax error
jdoodle.v:90: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:91: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:92: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:97: syntax error
jdoodle.v:97: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:98: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:99: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:102: syntax error
jdoodle.v:102: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:103: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:104: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:107: syntax error
jdoodle.v:107: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:108: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:109: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:112: syntax error
jdoodle.v:112: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:113: error: Invalid module instantiation
jdoodle.v:114: error: Invalid module instantiation
```

Comment: What kind of errors are you facing? Is it compilation or functional? Please provide the error message.

Comment: I updated the post with more information. Let me know if that was enough. I'm really sorry, I just really am not used to this coding language so I ask that you give me some patience.

Comment: It's best practice to limit your questions to one error at a time. This makes a better resource for future coders - they can use the question and answer if they have the same error.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are several syntax errors preventing this module from compiling.

- The semicolon after the module name 'main' is a syntax error.
- Semicolons in the IO list (after the module name are errors, need to be commas.
- You are tying to declare a state variables is the IO list area (just after the word module . Its an error. Put the declarations after IO listing.
  Search 'verilog state machine' to learn how and where to declare the state variables.
- You need non-blocking assignments (<=) rather than non blocking assignments (=) in the always block with the clock.
- Your always blocks were missing the timing control operator @.
- You were missing a 'end' keyword at the end of the module.
- The state machine does not have a :default state, which could cause some strange behavior.

I made these changes (did not add a :default state because it will modify your design intent).
Here is your code that now compiles using Mentor Questa on edaplayground.com
You did not post a testbench, there is no way to know if it behaves the way you want it to or not.
Search on 'basic verilog testbench' to get started on a testbench design.

```
module main
(
    input wire clk, 
    input wire reset,
    input wire x,
    input wire y,
    output reg n,
    output reg c
);
  
localparam   
    s0 = 2'b00,
    s1 = 2'b01,
    s2 = 2'b10,
    s3 = 2'b11;
    
reg [1:0] state_reg,state_next; 
  
always @(posedge clk, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset) begin
        state_reg <= s0;
    end
    else begin
        state_reg <= state_next;
    end
end 

always @(x, y, state_reg) begin 
    state_next = state_reg; 
    n = 0;
    c = 0;
    case (state_reg)
        s0 : begin
            if (x == 0 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0;
            end
            else if (x == 0 && y == 1) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
            else if (x== 1 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
             else if (x== 1 && y == 1) begin
                n = 1;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s1; 
            end
        end
        s1 : begin
              if (x == 0 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0;
            end
            else if (x == 0 && y == 1) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
            else if (x== 1 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
             else if (x== 1 && y == 1) begin
                n = 1;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s2; 
            end
        end
        s2 : begin
              if (x == 0 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0;
            end
            else if (x == 0 && y == 1) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
            else if (x== 1 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
             else if (x== 1 && y == 1) begin
                n = 1;
                c = 1;
                state_next = s3; 
            end
        end
        s3 : begin
             if (x == 0 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0;
            end
            else if (x == 0 && y == 1) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 0;
                state_next = s0; 
            end
            else if (x== 1 && y == 0) begin
                n = 0;
                c = 1;
                state_next = s3; 
            end
             else if (x== 1 && y == 1) begin
                n = 1;
                c = 1;
                state_next = s3; 
            end
        end
    endcase
  
end
  
endmodule
```